# Partitioning graph into 2 sets of vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to partition a connected graph into 2 sets of vertices, such that the difference of sum of edge-weights among vertices of each set is minimized.

For example, if a graph consists of vertices 1,2,3,4,5, consider this partition:

Set A - {1,2,3}

Set B - {4,5}

Sum A = {w(1 2) + w(2 3) + w(1 3)}

Sum B = {w(4 5)}

Diff = abs(Sum A - Sum B) ... (This is one possible partition difference.)

So, how do I find a partition such that the difference is minimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is NP hard because it is at least as hard as the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

### Sketch of proof

Consider a partition problem where we have the numbers {1,2,3,4,5} that we wish to partition into two sets with as small a difference as possible.

Construct the graph shown below:
[image: graph with node per number]

If someone comes up with an algorithm to solve your problem you can use the algorithm to partition this graph into two sets such that the sum of weights within each set is minimized.

In the optimal solution the blue and green nodes must be placed into different sets (because we have an edge with weight infinity connecting them).  The remaining nodes will be connected to either the blue or green nodes.  Call the ones connected to blue set1, and the ones connected to green set2.  This partition will give the optimal answer to the partition problem.

### Greedy algorithm

However, depending on the structure of your graph and values of the weights you may well be able to do a reasonable job.

For example, you could try:

1. Choose a random permutation of vertices
2. Loop through each vertex and assign to set 1 or 2 according to whichever minimises the objective function (which is just evaluated over the vertices assigned so far)

Repeat this algorithm a few times and keep track of the best score.

When you get down to just a few vertices left to be assigned, you could also try a brute force evaluation of all possible partitions of the remaining vertices to search for a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following algorithmic sketch is based on [Iterated Local Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_local_search). The idea is to greedily optimize the current solution until a local optimal solution is found. Then disturb this solution to overcome the local optimal solution. Always keep track of the best solution found so far.

1. Randomly divide the set of vertice into V1 and V2
2. Iterate

   - Calculate the costs (edge-weight-difference) of your current division
   - Select two random vertices v1 from V1 and v2 from V2
   - Check whether swapping these vertices (move v1 to V2 and v2 to V1) would lead to lower costs (edge-weight-difference). If so, swap vertices v1 and v2, else keep the sets.
3. Disturb a converged solution by swapping half of the vertices in V1 with half of the vertices in V2. Goto 2.

Iterated Local Search is a surprisingly effective and practical heuristic -- even for NP-complete problems.